# Setting up Cloud9 SSL App with Node JS

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, configuration

I've been playing around with the Cloud9 IDE and am having a great time with it. However, I'm trying to setup a simple https server with node js and I can't seem to get it to work. When I run the page, Cloud9 says 'Running Node Process' but when I visit the url that the server is supposed to respond to: https://workspace.user.c9.io the page says

```
Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server you are trying to contact is down either because it was stopped or is unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
node-web-proxy/0.4 Server at project-livec9f70a01ca28.rhcloud.com Port 8000
```

I created a test certificate with OPENSSL and am using the following code to set up my server. I can confirm that the OPENSSL certificate was built correctly.

```
var https = require("https");
var fs = require("fs");
var url = require("url");

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('certs/cert.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('certs/cert.pem')
};


// create a server

https.createServer(options, function(req, res) {

    console.log("This works!");

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("Hello world from Cloud9! Url:"+req.url);

}).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you able to make an http server work?

Answer (score 0):

you need `.listen(process.env.PORT,process.env.IP);`

It should say that when you start a program.